# bash script: if use with (conditon) or [condition]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a subtle question about if statement in bash script: what type of parenthesis should follow "if"?

I have two statements both working right now, but not working if I exchange () and [].

1.compare variable name

```
NAME="dada"
if [ "$NAME" == "dada" ]; then SOME COMMANDS; fi
```

If change [] to (), error:

```
dada: command not found
```

2.using grep

```
if ( grep -q "lalala" mytest.txt ); then SOME COMMANDS; fi
```

If change () to [], error:

```
[: lalala: binary operator expected
```

I read the linux man, which suggest using []. So is it because of using grep? Can we say generally if using another program inside if, we should use ()?

A side question about double quotation marks,
is it necessary to quote text in shell? for example, echo "$NAME" or NAME="fadfaj"?

I got confused because when I try to use $NAME plus some special characters such as "_" or space, where I need to use "\", I got different behaviour with and without "".

```
NAME="myfolder"
echo $NAME\_na
echo "$NAME\_na"
```

output

```
myfolder_na
myfolder\_na
```

I understand these are naive questions but I do appreciate all your help!

Comment: By the way, POSIX doesn't require the `test` command to support `==` as an operator (some shells, such as bash, support it as an extension), so it's safer to use `=` instead.

Comment: ...by the way, _don't_ use parenthesis unless you want their effect (creation of a subshell). `if (foo)` is slower than `if foo`, because it forks a subprocess, runs `foo` inside that subprocess, and then checks the subshell's return value. This also means that, unlike `if cd directory; the ...` -- which actually _does_ change directories in your current shell, and branches on whether or not it was successful in that -- `if (cd directory); then ...` won't actually change directories of the shell you're in, because it does the `cd` in the child process, not the main shell.

Comment: If you want a grouping operator that *doesn't* have side effects, that would be curly braces, not parenthesis. So: `false || {something; something-else; }` is more efficient than `false || (something; something-else)`.

Comment: By the way -- don't go editing extra questions into one SO topic. If you have more questions, search for whether anyone else asked them already, and if nobody else has, ask them separately. Otherwise, you risk having your question closed as too broad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your additional comments/tutorials on shell! It's of great help and possible save me from much future debugging! I will be careful about not asking multiple questions in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing following the `if` keyword is a *command*. The command is executed, and the condition is true if the command succeeds (exits with a status of `0`), false if it fails.

Though it looks like shell syntax, the `[` symbol is actually the name of a command (which happens to be built into the shell). For example, you could type just

```
[ "$NAME" = "dada" ]
```

at a shell prompt, with no `if`, and it would evaluate the same condition and set `$?`. You can also do this:

```
[ "$NAME" = "dada" ] && echo Yes
```

The `]` is a required last argument to the `[` command. Apart from that requirement, the `[` command is equivalent to the `test` command:

```
if test "$Name" = "data" ; then echo yes ; fi
```

Note that I've used `=` rather than `==`. The built-in `test`/`[` command in bash recognizes either form, but `=` is the original syntax, and some implementations don't recognize `==`.

`[` is the most common command to use with `if`, but you can use any command, including `grep:

```
if grep -q "lalala" mytest.txt; then SOME COMMANDS; fi
```

The parentheses are unnecessary. (If you add them, you're using a compound command rather than a simple command; there's no need to do so.)

See the bash manual (`info bash`) for more information. Search for

```
`test'
```

(with the backtick and apostrophe) for information on the built-in `test` command.

Bash also has a `[[` command which has some advantages over the older `[`.

Comment: Thank you so much Keith! Your answer is very clear! Would never think about [ as a command if you didn't point it out! By the way, would you mind also commenting a little bit on the use of double quotation marks or not in shell? thanks!

Comment: @CrazyFrog, regarding quotes -- always quote *all* expansions unless you have a specific and compelling reason not to. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments, and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: @CrazyFrog: One more change: it's safer to use `=` rather than `==` with `[` or `test`. Bash recognizes both, but `=` is the original syntax and some `[` or `test` implementations don't recognize `==`.